# Variational principle for a particle with varied mass

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass, variational-principle

I can't quite understand how the variational principle works. For a relativistic free particle we can find the extremum of the action
$$
S=-m\int ds
$$
and find the equations of motion. But what if the mass isn't constant and instead we have
$$
S=-\int m(s)ds.
$$
How does the variation work in this case?

Comment: A particle cannot lose or gain mass. An extended body, yes. There is no Lagrangian or Hamiltonian for bodies with variable mass.

Comment: Lets call it an action of extended body, the formulas won't change.

Comment: It is worth noting that the stress-energy tensor derived from this action will not be conserved unless $m$ is constant along the worldline.

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion, I've worded the question poorly. I will rephrase it soon and post an answer I was looking for when I wrote it in case anyone finds themselves in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

To apply the variational principle to the action you've written down, you need to consider the particle's spacetime position $x^\mu$ as a function of the parameter $s$ along the particle's path:
$$
S = - \int m \sqrt{ g_{\mu \nu}[x^\rho] \dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu} \, ds
$$
where we now view $x^\mu(s)$ as a function of the parameter $s$, with $\dot{x}^\mu$ as its first derivative.  We then apply the Euler-Lagrange equations to get a set of equations of motion for the world-line coordinate functions $x^\mu(s)$.  If we choose our parameter $s$ to be the proper time along the worldline, then these EOMs are equivalent to the geodesic equation.

With this in mind, it is not a big stretch to apply the Euler-Lagrange equations to a modified action of the form
$$
S = - \int m(s) \sqrt{ g_{\mu \nu}[x^\rho] \dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu} \, ds
$$
The process would be exactly the same:  apply the Euler-Lagrange equations to this action to get a set of equations of motion for $x^\mu(s)$.  The only difference is that this "action" now explicitly depends on $s$;  this is analogous to a classical particle Lagrangian that explicitly depends on $t$.

The resulting equations of motion will not have the same "nice" properties that the geodesic equations do, and (as noted in the comments) it may be difficult to give them a physical interpretation;  but you're free to write them out and try to solve them.